# Action Sheets and Alerts for deletions

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet, alerts

guys. Apple in their apps for delete action sometimes use Action Sheets or Alerts. And i dont understand, when i should use Action Sheets, and when Alerts. In the HIG Apple write, that:

> Alerts disrupt the user experience and should only be used in important situations like confirming purchases and destructive actions (such as deletions)

In [Photos and iCloud Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBKfD.png) for delete action Apple use Action Sheets(This destructive actions, but they use AS), but in [Reminders and Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA27C.png) for same action they use Alert. Please, help, what im should using for delete: Action Sheets or Alerts. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `UIActionSheet` & `UIAlertView` both are deprecated from iOS 8.0. You should use `'UIAlertController'` and set `preferredStyle` to `actionSheet`

But to answer your question above

It depends on use case basis as for example `UIActionSheet` will be used when you have more than 2 action e.g. Like , Share, Cancel and it will be displayed differently in iPhone (From the bottom) and iPad (In centre).

`UIAlertView` will be used when i have only two specific action like in your above question for delete confirmation it will display `OK` or `Cancel`. Hope this helps you to decide.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Sneha. I understand that `UIAlertView` the best choice for two specific action. But i dont understand why Apple use `UIActionSheet`(not `UIAlertView`) in two specific action.

Comment: @AnrewKravetz may be its just that they forgot to change it :) . Or there might be extra buttons which are added dynamically for different operations which we might not know.